# Emacs orgmode file cross-platform (linux + windows.)

Tags: emacs, cross-platform, org-mode

I'm in such situation. On desktop I have win7 x64, on notebook linux ubuntu x32. On win - emacs v24, on linux - emacs v23. I create orgmode file under win and put in smth using cyrilic symbols. Than I move file to linux and make some changes under that one (it opens and edits well), but they are not been saved, when I push "save" and move file again to win7. How I can edit the same file with cyrilic on win7 and lin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use UTF encoding. In your `~/.emacs`:

```
(prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)
(setq coding-system-for-read 'utf-8)
(setq coding-system-for-write 'utf-8)
```